# firebase_auth/invalid-credential Invalid Idp Response: access_token audience is not for this project

Tags: flutter

I get this error when i try a google sign with flutter web,I've added my client id i got from google cloud console in a meta tag in my index.html file, and I've also added sha1 and sha256 fingerprints in my firebase console as well as enable Google authentication in my firebase console for the project

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "AIzaSyBZ_p9JM8Bz6X70OyPS70dUdk0QBjP6wo4",
          appId:  "1:848613056189:web:9d18e75518499b79aa61d4",
          messagingSenderId: "848613056189",
          projectId: "gpharm-2ce1f",
          authDomain: "gpharm-2ce1f.firebaseapp.com",
          storageBucket: "gpharm-2ce1f.appspot.com"
      )
  );
  // if (!kIsWeb) {
  //   await GoogleSignInDart.register(
  //     clientId:
  //     '1078336123339-gigk2v6oam5gnev33l551p268logfd1i.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  //   );
  // }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const AuthPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AuthService{
  signInWithGoogle() async{
   try{
     final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

     final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;

     final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
         accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
         idToken: gAuth.idToken
     );

     return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
   }catch(e){
     var message = e.toString();
     print("this is the error: $message");
   }
  }
}
```

InkWell(

```
            onTap: () => AuthService().signInWithGoogle(),

            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, top: 16),
              child: Container(
                width: screenWidth,
                height: screenHeight*0.07,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Colors.red,
                  border: const Border(
                    top: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black26
                    ),
                    left: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black26
                    ),
                    right: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black26
                    ),
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black26
                    ),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 10,
                      child: SizedBox(
                              height: 25,
                              width: 25,
                              child: Image.asset("assets/google.png")
                          ),
                    ),

                  Center(
                    child: DefaultTextStyle(
                              style: GoogleFonts.openSans(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              child: const Text("Continue with Google")
                          ),
                  ),
                    ],
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and only got it working once I added the client id from the Google Cloud Console to the safelist client IDs from external projects in the Firebase Console:

Firebase Console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method tab -> Google Sign-in provider -> expand "Safelist client IDs from external projects (optional)" and add the ID, then save.

For those who want to know how to get the client ID from Google Cloud console: Google Cloud -> search for "Credentials" and select the result -> click on your OAuth 2.0 Client ID to see the full ID